# SQL Server 2014: Valid values of the database compatibility level are 80, 90, or 100

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and have SQL Server 2014 Standard edition. However, when I try to set the backward compatibility level to 110 (SQL Server 2012), I get this error:

> Valid values of the database compatibility level are 80, 90, or 100.

I tried to change it through the UI, only see these 3 values in drop down.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using also SQL Server 2014 database engine? Those compatibility levels are the ones from SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Apparently you're not connecting to a SQL Server 2014 database.

Comment: Try Select @@VERSION ... this will tell you what SQL Server version you are connected to.